How to configure Ghidra Memory Map use Script API?
How to configure "Memory Map" for RAM image use Ghidra Script API? For example, here is Memory layout created by python script:
.text start: 0x80004000
.text end: 0x8079e4d0
.text length: 0x79a4d0
.data start: 0x8079e4d4
.data end: 0x8093e220
.data length: 0x19fd4c
.bss_start: 0x80aad090
.bss_end: 0x80d19760
stack start: 0x80b15660
stack end: 0x80b19660

I want a) split RAM in two blocks: .text (code) and .data (data), and b) add 2 new blocks: .bss and stack. (both as overlay)
I set the start address to 0x80004000, and imported binary. It seems, Ghidra computes the addresses a little different (add 1 to length?) than python script I used to create the memory layout and this confuses things.
I think, for .bss and stack it could be
memory.createUninitializedBlock(".bss",toAddr(0x80aad090),0x26c6d0,True)
memory.createUninitializedBlock("stack",toAddr(0x80b15660),0x4000,True)

Not sure how to split ram block and what should be the full script.
